# What is the number of ways of choosing some objects from 2 boxes such that the number of objects chosen from differ by 1?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let us say we have 2 boxes of sizes X and Y, now we have to choose some number of objects from each of the box, **but under the constraint that the number of objects chosen in Box A is is less than the number of objects chosen in Box B by exactly 1**.

For example say the sizes are 2 and 4, then there are 4 ways of choosing $(0,1)$ , $12$ ways of choosing $(1,2)$ , 4 ways of choosing $(2,3)$ ,

And hence in total 20

Apparently this equals ${X+Y \choose X + 1 }$

But I don't understand how to arrive at it, any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every way to pick $k$ items from box $A$ there is a unique way to pick $x-k$ items: pick the objects not selected in the first instance. Thus the desired number is the same as the number of ways to pick $x-k$ and $k+1$ items from boxes A and B respectively for some $k$, i.e. the number of ways to pick $x+1$ items from both boxes combined. The answer is thus $\binom{x+y}{x+1}$.

Comment: I didn't understand how you arrived at the last equation, can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish Is this not the definition of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Yea, I didn't understand what you mean by "unique way to pick x-k items" and how you are roping "y" into this proof, can you please make it a little more detailed ? P.S. My combinatorics knowledge is restriced to high school, so few things may not be so obvious to me

Comment: @AjaySabarish Rather, there is a unique way to _not_ pick $k$ items given a way to pick $k$ items. $y$ is only needed at the last step, the number of ways to pick from both boxes); important to note is that $(x-k)+(k+1)$ is _constant_. (This ability to liberate $k$ from the final count is called Vandermonde's identity.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now.